# Parsing a String with quoted Fields like a CSV-line in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have to parse a variable input-string into a string-array.
The input is a CSV-style comma-separated field-list where each field has its own quoted string.
Because I dont want to write my own full-blown CSV-parser the only working solution I could create till now is this one:

```
$input = '"Miller, Steve", "Zappa, Frank", "Johnson, Earvin ""Magic"""'

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($input)
$stream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($bytes)
$parser = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser]::new($stream)
$parser.Delimiters = ','
$parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = $true
$list = $parser.ReadFields()

$list
```

Output looks like this:

```
Miller, Steve
Zappa, Frank
Johnson, Earvin "Magic"
```

Is there any better solution available via another .NET-library for Powersell?
In best case I could avoid this extra bytes-array and stream.
I am also not sure if this VisualBasic-Assembly will be avail on a long term.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With some extra precautions for security and to prevent inadvertent string extrapolation, you can combine [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) with [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)**, though note that [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375):

```sh
$fieldList = '"Miller, Steve", "Zappa, Frank", "Johnson, Earvin ""Magic""", "Honey, I''m $HOME"'

# Parse into array.
$fields = (
  Invoke-Expression ("Write-Output -- " + ($fieldList -replace '\$', "`0"))
) -replace "`0", '$$'
```

Note:

- `` -replace '\$', "`0" `` temporarily replaces literal `$` chars. in the input with NUL chars. to prevent accidental (or malicious) [string expansion (interpolation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375); the second `-replace` operation restores the original `$` chars.
  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for more information about the regex-based `-replace` operator.
- Prepending `Write-Output --`  to the resulting string and interpreting the result *as a PowerShell command* via `Invoke-Expression` causes `Write-Output` to parse the remainder of the string as individual arguments and output them as such. `--` ensures that any arguments that happen to look like `Write-Output`'s *own* parameters are *not* interpreted as such.
- ***If and only if* the input string is guaranteed to never contain embedded `$` characters**, the solution can be **simplified** to:

  ```
  $fields = Invoke-Expression "Write-Output -- $fieldList"
  ```

Outputting `$fields` yields the following:

```
Miller, Steve
Zappa, Frank
Johnson, Earvin "Magic"
Honey, I'm $HOME
```

---

**Explanation and list of constraints**:

The solution relies on making the input string part of a *string* whose *content* is a syntactically valid `Write-Output` call, with the input string serving as the latter's *arguments*. `Invoke-Expression` then evaluates this string as if its content had directly been submitted as a command and therefore executes the `Write-Output` command. Based on how PowerShell parses command arguments, this implies the following constraints:

- **Supported field separators:**

  - Either: **`,`-separated** (with per-field (unquoted) leading and/or trailing whitespace getting removed, as shown above).
  - Or: **whitespace-separated**, using one or more whitespace characters between the fields.
- **Non-/quoting of embedded fields**:

  - Fields can be *quoted*:

    - If **single-quoted** (`'...'`), field-*internal* `'` characters must be escaped as `''`.
    - If **double-quoted**, field-*internal* `"` characters must be escaped as either `""` or `` `" ``.
  - Fields can also be *unquoted*:

    - However, such fields mustn't contain any PowerShell argument-mode *metacharacters* (of these, `< > @ #` are only metacharacters at the *start* of a token):

      ```
       <space> ' " ` , ; ( ) { } | & < > @ #
      ```

---

**Alternative, via `ConvertFrom-Csv`**:

[iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67434176/45375) shows a solution based on [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv), given that the field list embedded in the input string is *comma*-separated (`,`):

- On the one hand, it is more limited in that it only supports `"..."`-quoting of fields and `""`-escaping of field-internal `"`, and doesn't support fields separated by varying amounts of whitespace (only).
- On the other hand, it is more flexible, in that it supports *any single-character separator* between the fields (irrespective of incidental leading/trailing per-field whitespace), which can be specified via the `-Delimiter` parameter.

What makes the solution awkward is the need to *anticipate the max. number of embedded fields* and to provide *dummy headers* (column names) for them (`-Header (0..99)`) in order to make `ConvertFrom-Csv` work, which is both fragile and potentially wasteful.

However, a simple trick can bypass this problem: Submit the input string *twice*, in which case `ConvertFrom-Csv` treats the fields in the input string as both the column names *and* as the column values of the one and only output row (object), whose values can then be queried:

```sh
$fieldList = '"Miller, Steve", "Zappa, Frank", "Johnson, Earvin ""Magic""", "Honey, I''m $HOME"'

# Creates the same array as the solution at the top.
$fields = ($fieldList, $fieldList | ConvertFrom-Csv).psobject.Properties.Value
```

Comment: Submitting the input string twice is really a smart to resolve the unknown number of column names 

Answer (score 2):

If the list is limited, you might use the parser of the [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) cmdlet, like:

```
$List = '"Miller, Steve", "Zappa, Frank", "Johnson, Earvin ""Magic""", "Honey, I''m $HOME"'
($List | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (0..99)).PSObject.Properties.Value.Where{ $Null -ne $_ }
Miller, Steve
Zappa, Frank
Johnson, Earvin "Magic"
Honey, I'm $HOME
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, though the `-Header (0..99)` part is a bit awkward. A simple solution is to supply the input string _twice_: `($List, $List | ConvertFrom-Csv).psobject.Properties.Value`