# How can i add set of values to helm upgrade command in powershell script with a variable

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a powershell script, that take my variable and deliver it to the my helm upgrade command

```
param
(   
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $HELM_SET
)
    helm upgrade --install myrelease -n dev my_service.tgz $HELM_SET
```

My HELM_SET var contains:
`--set config.vali=x --set config.spring=v1`

But helm said after upgrade:
Error: unknown flag: --set config.vali
helm.go:88: [debug] unknown flag: --set config.vali

if i'm add "--set" into
`helm upgrade --install myrelease -n dev my_service.tgz --set $HELM_SET` 
and my HELM_SET var now contains:
`config.vali=x --set config.spring=v1`

after upgrade i receive that my config:vali var is `x --set config.spring=v1`

Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you executing this script? Is it a function or just ps1 file with a `param(...)` block? If it's a external script, are you executing it from powershell or from cmd? Do you run it like this: `.\script.ps1 --set config.vali=x --set config.spring=v1` ?

Answer (score 1):

**If you're passing `$HELM_SET` as a *single string* encoding *multiple arguments*, you cannot pass it as-is to a command**.

Instead, you'll need to parse this string into an *array* of *individual* arguments.

In the ***simplest* case**, using the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), which splits the string into an array of tokens by whitespace:

```sh
helm upgrade --install myrelease -n dev my_service.tgz (-split $HELM_SET)
```

However, **if your arguments include *quoted strings*** (e.g. `--set config.spring="v 1"`), more work is needed, because the quoted strings must be recognize as such, so as not to break them into multiple tokens by their *embedded* whitespace:

```sh
# Note: Use of Invoke-Expression is safe here, but should generally be avoided.
$passThruArgs = (Invoke-Expression ('Write-Output -- ' + $HELM_SET -replace '\$', "`0")) -replace "`0", '$$'

helm upgrade --install myrelease -n dev my_service.tgz $passThruArgs
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423062/45375) for an explanation of this technique.

---

**If you control the *invocation* of your script, a *simpler solution* is available:**

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you can use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property of a parameter declaration to collect all arguments (that aren't bound to other parameters):

```sh
param
(   
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    $__passThruArgs # Choose an exotic name that won't be used in the actual arguments
)

helm upgrade --install myrelease -n dev my_service.tgz $__passThruArgs
```

Instead of passing the pass-through arguments *as a single string*, you would then pass them *as individual arguments*:

```sh
./yourScript.ps1 --set config.vali=x --set config.spring=v1
```

Comment: I'm wondering, wouldn't `param([parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)][string]$HELM_SET)` work in this case?

Comment: With a param block like above and then as an example `bash -c $HELM_SET` if I call the script like `.\script.ps1 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it works just fine without the need for `-split` or passing the argument as a string using quotes.

Comment: Excellent point re `ValueFromRemainingArguments`,  @SantiagoSquarzon - please see my update. As for `bash -c`: you're passing a single string to _another_ scripting engine, and _it_ then interprets that string as source code. It is equivalent to calling `eval` on a string from within `bash` / calling `Invoke-Expression` on a string from within PowerShell.

Comment: Makes sense, it also explains why I must type constraint the argument to `[string]` using this method for `bash -c` but I couldn't think of a binary to test this on. Thanks.